# Object aggregations in Querydsl-jpa

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data, hql, querydsl

I would like to ask if there is any possibility to use object aggregation functions in JPA (which uses HQL). Functions like `json_agg()`

I would like to achieve something like. So the goal is to take entity and transform it into string.

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("jsonb_agg(json_build_object('entity', {0}))", qEntity.id)
```

Why I try to do I am getting `org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode` error. I´ve read that problem is I can not use HQL cause I can not use the HQL object properties in json aggregation functions.

I would like to avoid using querydsl-sql as much as I can (It makes complications in docker app deployment, It needs to be connected to database etc). **So is there any way how to agregate objects like this using HQL?** I am using spring-data-jpa so these is opportunity to use this tool to if there is better solution in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your QueryDSL snippet looks just fine, but you need to register custom functions for `JSONB_AGG` and `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` as well as custom types for the JSONB result.

For the custom JSONB type you can use the `JsonBinaryType` from the [`hibernate-types`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) library.

For the custom function, you need to create a `MetadataBuilderInitializer`  that registers the SQL functions with Hibernate. you can take inspiration from my [`hibernate-types-querydsl-apt`](https://github.com/jwgmeligmeyling/hibernate-types-querydsl-apt) library (for example `ArrayFunctionInitializer`). Applied to JSON functions specifically, you would end up with something along the lines of:

```
public class ArrayFunctionInitializer implements MetadataBuilderInitializer {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder, StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("json_build_object", new StandardSQLFunction("json_build_object", JsonBinaryType.INSTANCE));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("jsonb_agg", new StandardSQLFunction("jsonb_agg", JsonBinaryType.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I´ve read that hibernate-types article and that seems to me I can store a json as an column. And thats not really what I want. I would like to use the structure as I have right now (so qEntity has linked some other entites) and just use group by and as a result be able to pick whole entity (if possible) or at least create json with picked qClass fields. Plus I do not really understand how to use that Initializer in my Spring MVC code using Querydsl-jpa.

Comment: You need to provide the type class described in that blogpost as argument for the return type when registering the custom SQL function with Hibernate. In order to register the MetadataContributor with Hibernate you’ll have to create a service provider file.